# How to update variables in script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Script should restart service and save current data and time in file after memory usage reach the limit. But it doesn't save current time and in second `if` when service is stopped it doesn't do `else`. It always show the same values in `$data` and `$stat`. I am not sure where I made mistake.

```
$proc = 'process name'
$serv = 'service name*'
$ram = 10MB
$inter = 1
$data = Get-Date -format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
$log = "c:\log.txt"
$stat = Get-Process $proc -EA SilentlyContinue

while ($true) {
    if ((Get-Process $proc -EA SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Exp ws) -gt $ram) {
        Restart-Service $serv
        Add-Content -path $log -value ($data + "`t" + "Restarting")
        Start-Sleep -m 10000
        if ($stat -ne $null) {
            Add-Content -path $log -value "Working"
        } else {
            Start-Service $serv
            Add-Content -path $log -value ($data + "`t" + "Starting")
        }
    }

    Start-Sleep -s $inter
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statements in your variable assignments are evaluated at the time of assignment, not when the variable is used. To get the latter you could define the statements as scriptblocks:

```
$data = { Get-Date -format 'yyyy\/MM\/dd HH:mm:ss' }
$stat = { Get-Process mysqld -ea SilentlyContinue }
```

Use the call operator (`&`) in an expression (`()`) or subexpression (`$()`) to evaluate the scriptblocks at a later point in your script:

```
if ((&$stat) -ne $null) {
    Add-Content -Path $log -Value "Working"
} else {
    Start-Service $serv
    Add-Content -Path $log -Value "$(&$data)`tStarting"
}
```

Probably a more convenient way is to define the operations as functions:

```
function Get-Timestamp { Get-Date -format 'yyyy\/MM\/dd HH:mm:ss' }
function Test-MySQLProcess { [bool](Get-Process mysqld -EA SilentlyContinue) }
```

and use them like this:

```
if (Test-MySQLProcess) {
    Add-Content -Path $log -Value "Working"
} else {
    Start-Service $serv
    Add-Content -Path $log -Value "$(Get-Timestamp)`tStarting"
}
```

---

As a side note, you should escape forward slashes in date format strings, otherwise Windows substitutes them with whatever date separator character is configured in your system's regional settings.